# Upload file not working as expected in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, image-upload

I'm using following code to upload files to server.

```
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;

class Test implements ObserverInterface {
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $_filesystem;
    protected $_fileUploaderFactory;



public function __construct(
            , StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
            , \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
            , \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $fileUploaderFactory
    ) {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_filesystem = $filesystem;
        $this->_fileUploaderFactory = $fileUploaderFactory;
        $this->marketplaceData = $marketplaceData;
        $this->areamasterModel = $areamasterModel;
    }

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
    .
    .
    .        
    $testImage = $this->fileUpload ( $_FILES ['test_image'], 'Image', 'test_image' );
    }

public function fileUpload($image, $folder, $fileId) {
        if (isset ( $image ) && $image ['size'] > 0) {
            $currenttimestamp = date ( 'Y-m-d H-i-s' );
            $pathurl = $this->_storeManager->getStore ()->getBaseUrl ( \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA ) . $folder . '/';
            $mediaDir = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead ( DirectoryList::MEDIA )->getAbsolutePath ();
            $mediapath = $this->_mediaBaseDirectory = rtrim ( $mediaDir, '/' );
            $imageName = $currenttimestamp . $image ['name']; // Prepending with time stamp to avoid duplication of file name
            $imageName = preg_replace ( '/\s+/', '_', $imageName ); // Replacing single/multiple spaces with underscore in file name
            $uploader = $this->_fileUploaderFactory->create ( [
                    'fileId' => $fileId
            ] );
            $uploader->setAllowedExtensions ( [
                    'jpg',
                    'jpeg',
                    'gif',
                    'png',
                    'pdf'
            ] );
            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles ( true );
            $path = $mediapath . '/' . $folder . '/';
            $result = $uploader->save ( $path );
            return $imageName;
        }
    }
```

Above code works well and upload files to the mentioned folder name but the name of the file doesn't append datetime stamp at the start.